# Java spark app hangs when using method reference

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I'm writing a Spark app in Java called MyApp, and I have the following code:

```
final JavaRDD<MyClass<MyInnerClass>> myRDD = ...
myRDD.repartition(50).map(ObjectMapperFactory.OBJECT_MAPPER_MIXIN::writeValueAsString)
.saveAsTextFile(outputPath, GzipCodec.class);
```

When I run the tests for my package, this app hangs. However, if I use a lambda function instead of passing in a method reference, like this

```
myRDD.repartition(50).map(t -> ObjectMapperFactory.OBJECT_MAPPER_MIXIN.writeValueAsString(t))
     .saveAsTextFile(outputPath, GzipCodec.class);
```

Then the tests work fine. The only change is in the map statement. I am using Java 8, Spark 1.5.2 and running the cluster in local mode.

EDIT: If I run the test for MyApp by itself, the test works fine with the old code. However, if I run the full test suite, that's when the app starts to hang. There are other java spark apps in my package.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spark, but I'll point out that there is a slight difference between the lambda and method reference in your case. The method reference directly references `ObjectMapperFactory.OBJECT_MAPPER_MIXIN`, immediately initializing it if necessary. The lambda won't initialize anything until it's actually used.

Comment: If I just pass in a regular ObjectMapper, I get serialization errors, so it looks like using Mixins causes the app to swallow the errors.

Comment: I'd like to say @shmosel is right.
If method reference is initialized directly, I mean with its physical address or something, then it will be a problem for worker nodes to execute it. Because there are some resource only in driver, which worker nodes can't access.
That's why we get serialization errors.